# Child thread seems to be blocked by main thread in Rust, causing unbounded channel to grow infinitely

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm experiencing something weird in my first real Rust program.
The program is meant to read data from FPGA memory (abstracted as binary files created on a CentOS system by proprietary drivers supplied with the FPGA) and write it to an HDF5 file. The FPGA reads ten vectors (512x16bit each) at 400 Hz (every 2.5ms).

Initially I ran into problems where writing the HDF5 file took on average around 1ms, but sometimes took as long as 15ms, leading to the loss of data. So I decided to write the data to HDF5 asynchronously from the reading, using Rust's mpsc facility (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/index.html), making it irrelevant that the writing sometimes took more than 2.5ms, as long as it on average took less.

For development purposes I used the following snippet to simulate the 400 Hz update rate, eventually this will be done via polling the FPGA memory for an incremented counter or via an interrupt:

`while loop_start.elapsed().as_micros() < MAIN_SLEEP_TIME {}` where `loop_start` is an instance of `std::time::Instant::now()`

My problem is that the writing thread seems to be affected by this delay in the main thread. The writing thread's loop always takes approx. `MAIN_SLEEP_TIME` to finish, leading to the channel between the threads growing as data is added and not read fast enough, eventually crashing the program due to being out of memory. This is the code I've used to reproduce it, with comments on where the problem occurs:

```
use std::{thread, time};
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver};
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;


const MAIN_SLEEP_TIME: u128 = 2500; //Number of micros to sleep for


#[derive(Debug)]
struct DataContainer{
    internal_count: u64,
    fake_vector: [u8; 10240]
}

fn main() {
    let mut loop_counter: u64 = 0;
    let mut fake_counter: u8 = 0;
    let (datasender, datareceiver) = channel::<DataContainer>();
    //The bug causes this unbounded channel to grow infinitely and cause an OOM error as t => inf
    let mut data = DataContainer {
        internal_count: 0,
        fake_vector: [127; 10240]
    };

    let write_thread = thread::spawn(|| {
        write_thread(datareceiver);
    });

    loop {

        let loop_start = time::Instant::now();
        
        data = DataContainer{
            internal_count: loop_counter,
            fake_vector: [fake_counter; 10240]
        };
        loop_counter += 1;
        fake_counter += 1;

        datasender.send(data);

        while loop_start.elapsed().as_micros() < MAIN_SLEEP_TIME {
            //This loop causes the loop in write_thread too always take ~MAIN_SLEEP_TIME to complete
            //This is also the case if replaced with thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_micros(MAIN_SLEEP_TIME))
        }
    }

}

fn write_thread(receiver: Receiver<DataContainer>) {
    let mut write_counter = 0;
    let mut file = File::create("output.bin").unwrap();
    loop {
        let now = time::Instant::now();
        let reecived_data = receiver
            .recv_timeout(time::Duration::from_millis(50)).unwrap();
        file.write_all(&reecived_data.fake_vector);
        println!("Wrote loop {}! This took {} us!", write_counter, now.elapsed().as_micros());
        //This println will print something akin to "Wrote loop [n]! This took [~MAIN_SLEEP_TIME] us!"
        write_counter += 1;
    }
}
```

The output looks something like this:

```
Wrote loop 0! This took 60 us!
Wrote loop 1! This took 2298 us!
Wrote loop 2! This took 2420 us!
Wrote loop 3! This took 2487 us!
Wrote loop 4! This took 2538 us!
Wrote loop 5! This took 2462 us!
Wrote loop 6! This took 2471 us!
Wrote loop 7! This took 2484 us!
Wrote loop 8! This took 2507 us!
Wrote loop 9! This took 2468 us!
Wrote loop 10! This took 2489 us!
Wrote loop 11! This took 2461 us!
Wrote loop 12! This took 2492 us!
Wrote loop 13! This took 2488 us!
Wrote loop 14! This took 2520 us!
Wrote loop 15! This took 2471 us!
Wrote loop 16! This took 2494 us!
Wrote loop 17! This took 2470 us!
Wrote loop 18! This took 2483 us!
Wrote loop 19! This took 2487 us!
Wrote loop 20! This took 2490 us!
```

With `MAIN_SLEEP_TIME` set to 5000:

```
Wrote loop 0! This took 50 us!
Wrote loop 1! This took 5066 us!
Wrote loop 2! This took 5989 us!
Wrote loop 3! This took 5956 us!
Wrote loop 4! This took 5972 us!
Wrote loop 5! This took 5987 us!
Wrote loop 6! This took 5999 us!
Wrote loop 7! This took 5977 us!
Wrote loop 8! This took 5999 us!
Wrote loop 9! This took 5982 us!
Wrote loop 10! This took 5990 us!
Wrote loop 11! This took 6009 us!
Wrote loop 12! This took 6008 us!
Wrote loop 13! This took 5975 us!
Wrote loop 14! This took 5953 us!
Wrote loop 15! This took 5991 us!
Wrote loop 16! This took 5995 us!
Wrote loop 17! This took 5969 us!
Wrote loop 18! This took 5984 us!
Wrote loop 19! This took 5987 us!
Wrote loop 20! This took 5989 us!
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I can't quite follow your question, sadly. If you put something into the channel every 2500us, then you get something out every 2500us, meaning, your receiver will wait in `recv_timeout` for 2500us. What here is a surprise to you? How would you expected your program to behave?

Comment: If you say that you are getting a crash, I can't see why. Your code should be very stable the way it is, and the channel should be constantly empty. Also, I'm fairly certain your second example isn't set to 5000, but 6000 ;)

Comment: You're not actually measuring how long it takes to write something to disk, you're measuring how long it takes to receive an item *and* write it to disk, which will obviously always be about as fast as the producer is. Move your `let now` after `let received_data` (so, just above `file.write_all`) to actually measure how long it takes to write to disk and I can almost guarantee you you'll see "faster" results